# Django Duplicate Detection

Tags: django

I've got a large database of contacts, each owned by a specific user.  I'm attempting to remove any duplicates within each user's contact list.  The simplest seemed to be to annotate with a string of user_id||name||address||zipcode, Count, and filter by count > 1.  This has worked in most cases, but I've got some weird holdouts. Can anyone point out what I'm missing?

Here's some code... I'm filtering to a specific name that I know has duplicates for testing.

```
neighbors = neighbors.filter(name__icontains='JOHN WILLIAMS')

keyed_neighbors = neighbors.values('user_id', 'name', 'address', 'zipcode', 'pk'
    ).annotate(dupe_id=Concat(
        Cast('user_id', CharField(max_length=25)), Value('||'), 
        Upper('name'), Value('||'), 
        Upper('address'), Value('||'), 
        Substr('zipcode', 1, 5), Value('||'), 
        Upper('address_line_two'), output_field=CharField()))

dupes = keyed_neighbors.annotate(dupe_id_count=Count('dupe_id'))
```

Here's a subset of the dupe_ids that I get back, and the counts:

```
    {'dupe_id': u'174563||JOHN WILLIAMS||222 WEDGEFIELD DR||28376||', 'dupe_id_count': 1}
    {'dupe_id': u'175875||JOHN WILLIAMS||4 TALLIN CT||29607||', 'dupe_id_count': 1}
    {'dupe_id': u'175875||JOHN WILLIAMS||4 TALLIN CT||29607||', 'dupe_id_count': 1}
    {'dupe_id': u'177178||JOHN WILLIAMS||5106 PAUL PEEL PL||28348||', 'dupe_id_count': 1}
    {'dupe_id': u'51||JOHN WILLIAMS||2410 COLGATE DR||28304||', 'dupe_id_count': 1}
    {'dupe_id': u'51||JOHN WILLIAMS||2410 COLGATE DR||28304||', 'dupe_id_count': 1}
    {'dupe_id': u'51||JOHN WILLIAMS||4 TALLIN CT||29607||', 'dupe_id_count': 1}
```

If anyone can shine a light on my mistake I'd very much appreciate it.

Comment: You probably only have to concat user_id and pk. what an example of a holdout?- or is the "JOHN WILLIAMS||4 TALLIN CT" an example and the dupe count should be 2?

Comment: None of those have an 'address_line_2'.  Are there examples where the count worked that are missing this field, or is this limited to the outliers?

Comment: @Nealium: Yes - that's one of the holdouts.  There's also two 2410 Colgate Dr.  The reason for the concatenation is to that string containing all the things that could make an entry not a duplicate (like having two users with the same street name, but are actually in different zipcodes).  So I'm annotating that key string, and then counting the occurrences of that same "dupe_id"

Comment: @SamSparx: Yup, I processed a few thousand that also didn't have address_line_2.